# how to calculate the Sum of sales associated to different users

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have following Tables in my database:

```
    Sales
   -------------------------
    id  client  account sale
    1   X       A2      400
    2   X       A2      300
    3   X       A1      100
    4   X       A1      200

    Account                         Users
    --------------------            -------------------------------------
    accountid   account             id      username first_name last_name
    A1          Acc1                U1      abc      Manish     Goyal
    A2          Acc2                U2      xyz      Yogita     Sharma
    A3          Acc3                U3      jkl      Nitish     Malhotra        

    AccountUsers
    ------------------------
    id  accountid       user
    1   A1              U1
    2   A1              U2
    3   A1              U3
```

I want to get the Sum of sale column from sales table which is associated to the account and account access by Manish and Yogita user.

I wrote the following SQL

```
SELECT SUM(Sales.sale) as total_sale, Account.account, Sales.client
FROM sales
INNER JOIN Account ON Sales.accountid = Account.accountid 
INNER JOIN AccountUsers ON AccountUsers.accountid = Account.accountid 
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.id = AccountUsers.user 
WHERE ( (trim(CONCAT(Users.first_name,' ',Users.last_name)) = 'Manish Goyal') OR (trim(CONCAT(Users.first_name,' ',Users.last_name)) = 'yogita sharma'))
```

I got the following Result:

```
client account total_sale
X       Acc1    600
X       Acc2    1400
```

However, I want to get following result:

```
Output
client account total_sale
X       Acc1    300
X       Acc2    700
```

The thing is if a sale is associated to both account's users then sum the sale is returned based on account.
I'm stuck over there. 
Thank in Advance!...

Comment: I think 'Manish Goyal' and 'yogita sharma' both get 300 total_sale because both uses have same accountid in AccountUsers table.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause somewhere

Comment: I added group by clause to sql query but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have some mistake in your question. Please check the below table that is mentioned by you

```
AccountUsers
    ------------------------
    id  accountid       user
    1   A1              U1
    2   A1              U2
    3   A1              U3
```

In this all the users are linked to same accountid. Is this correct from your side?

I think you can query the output directly and get the sum of sales without any additional effort.

---

I tried to get the out put that you would like to get.

You may look in the below fiddle to see the answers. This may not be completely correct as what you want. But may help you get the answer. Please go through and verify.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38c0f/1

---

```
SELECT Account.account,sum(Sales.sale)
FROM  Sales 
inner join Account on Account.accountid=Sales.account
GROUP BY  Sales.account,Account.account;


SELECT Account.account,sum(Sales.sale)
FROM  Sales 
inner join Account on Account.accountid=Sales.account
where Sales.account in (
SELECT Sales.account
FROM sales
left JOIN Account ON Sales.account = Account.accountid 
left JOIN AccountUsers ON AccountUsers.accountid = Account.accountid 
left JOIN Users ON Users.id = AccountUsers.users
WHERE ( ((CONCAT(Users.first_name,' ',Users.last_name)) = 'Manish Goyal') 
       OR ((CONCAT(Users.first_name,' ',Users.last_name)) = 'yogita sharma'))
       group by Sales.Account
)
GROUP BY  Sales.account,Account.account;
```

Comment: Yupps, this is correct. I need to sum of those sales which are linked with accounts and the accounts are accessed by Manish and Yogita User.

Comment: Please select as accepted solution if this resolution solves your problem. Bye. :-)